# Three.js loadTexture onload callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, three.js

How to wait for the image to load in three.js? I'm doing the following:

```
function myClass {

  var IMAGE, TEXTURE;

  IMAGE = ...; // properly initialised image object

  function asyncFunc() {

    TEXTURE.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    ... // rest of code

  }

  myClass.prototype.loadSomething = function(args) {

    var base64Image = IMAGE.src;

    TEXTURE = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(
      base64Image,
      {},
      asyncFunc(args)
    );

  };

}
```

In my main.js I call the following:

```
var x = new myClass();
x.loadSomething(args);
```

However, I get an error that `TEXTURE` is undefined. I expected that the `asyncFunc()` would be called after the texture is loaded, but it isn't.

Any ideas on how to handle async texture loading?

Comment: in your `aryncFunc(args)`, `TEXTURE` is out of scope, but `args` is `TEXTURE`.

Comment: Let me try to "reference" the `TEXTURE`, I had a doubt that it's out of scope, I hope you're right.